# Sum Total Login Time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using MySQL 5.6 and want to calculate sum (in-mins) against below data through SQL statement:

third column for just information and means i am expecting 15 value

```
 
Status   Date_Time            Total_hours
```

LogIn    2016-01-14 00:00:00
LogOut   2016-01-14 09:00:00    9
LogIn    2016-01-14 10:00:00
LogOut   2016-01-14 14:00:00    4
LogIn    2016-01-14 16:00:00
LogOut   2016-01-14 18:00:00    2

`hours Total ==>>  15`

Comment: What is your desired output, and have you attempted a query yet?  If you want the difference in minutes between login and logout, I think we will need a third column "session" to group the two events.

Comment: data didn't have chances to group on any column. Unfortunately, yet i am not able to run any command because this requirement never face before it.

Comment: Is that everything in your data structure? just two fields?

Answer (score 0):

Updated to include your table and field names.

```
SELECT
loggedin.InOutStatus,
MAX(loggedin.Date_Time) AS start_time,
loggedout.Date_TimeAS end_time,
TIMEDIFF(MAX(loggedin.Date_Time), loggedout.Date_Time)
FROM empstatuslog AS loggedin
INNER JOIN empstatuslog AS loggedout ON (loggedin.InOutStatus = loggedout.InOutStatus
                                     AND loggedout.Date_Time > loggedin.Date_Time)
WHERE loggedin.InOutStatus= 'LogIn'
AND loggedout.InOutStatus= 'LogOut'
GROUP BY loggedin.InOutStatus
```

Comment: thanks for your answer: More information as follow: table name empstatuslog   column name: InOutStatus & Date_Time

Comment: Updated to include your table and field names.

Comment: thanks matt for your efforts: I am running statement as follow but not giving any record but when placing commit then giving wrong output. any help

Comment: Are there only the 2 columns in your table?

Comment: SELECT  login.`InOutStatus`,
   MAX(login.`Date_Time`) AS start_time,
   login.`Date_Time` AS end_time,
   TIMEDIFF(MAX(login.`Date_Time`),login.`Date_Time`)
 FROM `empstatuslog` login
 INNER JOIN `empstatuslog` logout ON login.`InOutStatus`=logout.InOutStatus AND logout.`Date_Time`>login.`Date_Time`  
 WHERE login.`Status`='Success'
 AND   login.`InOutStatus`='LogIn'
 -- AND   logOut.`InOutStatus`='LogOut' 
 GROUP BY login.InOutStatus
 ORDER BY login.`Date_Time`

Comment: third column for just information and means i am expecting 15 value